# splash screen showing up on every refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have my splash screen showing up on app start for 3seconds

```js
<script>
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    setTimeout(function () {
        body.setAttribute('ng-app', 'app');
        angular.bootstrap(body, ['ng', 'app']);
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

i have a div with style on ng-cloak

```
<div class="splash img-responsive" ng-cloak="">
<div id="imageContainer">

</div>
```

my css for splash is

```css
.splash {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /*filter: alpha(opacity=60);*/
    /*opacity: 0.6;*/
    background-image: url(../images/img.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display: none;
}
```

the splash screen i need only on angular app start, but this shows up on every page refresh/reload. how to avoid that and show splash screen only on app start.

Comment: Can you make a plunker please ?

Comment: its kind of complex to replicate...

Comment: Why you don't make a cookie and check if exist before make your timeout ?

Comment: You could try to hide your splash when it has appear once ?
`ng-show`will help you in this way.
@CyrilBeeckman cookie or localstorage could work too yep :)

Comment: since angular makes single page applications, I think every page reload is app start..

Comment: how to know if it has appeared once.. and hide it next time? @Zooly

Comment: I'm thinking about something like this : (once it has appear) `localStorage.setItem('splash',true)` and `<div class="splash" ng-show="localStorage.getItem('splash')">`

Comment: also need to set false to make it hide? @Zooly

Comment: I think, try it :)

Comment: ok ill try and post the answer ..thanks anyway :)

Comment: no luck.. @Zooly

Comment: @SanjanaHE my bad ! ng-show won't display the element, but it still created in the DOM. Use ng-if instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue at simplest! 
In my controller wrote this piece of code

```
 $scope.showDiv = true;
        $scope.hide = function () {
            $scope.showDiv = false;
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.showDiv = true;
            }, 3000);
        }
```

so now i wanted splash screen on app start and after 2-3sec display of login box

```
 <div class="login-page">
    <div class="form-page" ng-init=hide() ng-show="showDiv"></div></div>
```

Was able to show splash screen for 3 sec and show login box

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own method to show the splashscreen only when YOU want

remove the JS code that allows the splashscreen to show up, and all you need to do is to show on the foreground the image to show(by html), hiding the entire index page. After 3 seconds, you can set that image to `display=none;` and the trick is done.

This logic allows you to arbitrary decide when to show the splash image and when to hide it or when to not show it at all.